# Can't hold the value of SelectNode in a variable from a xml document

Tags: xml, powershell

I am using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to parse the data of an XML document that I have created, so far everything is working like this:

```
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//key")[0]
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//value")[0]
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//key")[1]
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//value")[1]
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//key")[2]
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//value")[2]
```

All this works fine but I want to parse the values into a variable like this:

```
$a1 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("//key")[0]
$a2 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("//value")[0]
$b1 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("//key")[1]
$b2 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("//value")[1]
$c1 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("//key")[2]
$c2 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("//value")[2]
```

Then if I try `Write-Host $a1` it will not display the value, how can I get the variable to hold this value.  I tried using `SelectSingleNode` but got the same results.  I tried using `.InnerText`, `.InnerHtml`, .Value all of these will display correctly without using the $variables so how can I hold the information in a variable.

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xml:space="preserve">
<triggers>
<defined>true</defined>
<triggerDefinition>
<id>1</id>
<name>After successful build plan</name>
<userDescription>Auto release</userDescription>
<isEnabled>true</isEnabled>
<pluginKey>com.atlassian.bamboo.triggers.atlassian-bamboo-triggers:afterSuccessfulPlan</pluginKey>
<triggeringRepositories/>
<config>
<item>
<key>deployment.trigger.afterSuccessfulPlan.triggeringBranch</key>
<value>INT-LOAN</value>
</item>
<item>
<key>deployment.trigger.afterSuccessfulPlan.triggeringPlan</key>
<value>INT-LOAN</value>
</item>
<item>
<key>deployment.trigger.afterSuccessfulPlan.branchSelectionMode</key>
<value>INHERITED</value>
</item>
</config>
</triggerDefinition>
</triggers>
<bambooDelimiterParsingDisabled>true</bambooDelimiterParsingDisabled>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There's a / missing in the XPath expression in your a1 example

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen cheers but that was just a typo from trying so many different ways it is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *select a subnode / attribute for* your selected node. For example, if you want to output the `Id` attribute value using `Write-Host`:

```
Write-Host $a1.Id
```

---

**Edit:**

I copied your XML, invoking this actual outputs `deployment.trigger.afterSuccessfulPlan.triggeringBranch`:

```
[xml]$xdoc = Get-Content 'your_xml_path'
$a1 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("//key")[0]
Write-Host $a1.InnerText
```

Comment: If the last node contains an inner text: `Write-Host $a1.InnerText`

Comment: I edited my answer. You probably miss something to tell us, just try my example (fill in the path before)

Comment: yes you are right that works but the reason why it doesn't work for me is becasue my xml file is actually larger than what I showed there so it can't get the correct value I will try and show you the whole xml file.

Comment: I somehow receive an error when I try to load it: `The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the 
specified node is the wrong type.`

Comment: Unfortunately not and I don't have much time to invest right now :-/

Comment: nevermind, I messed it up (forgot the `Get-Content` here). It also works with your updated xml!

Comment: 1. [xml]$xdoc = Get-Content 'C:\Users\.\myFile.xml'  2. $a1 = $xdoc.SelectNodes("key")[0]  3. Write-Host $a1.InnerText, shouldn't that work?

Comment: it should if you replace `key` with `//key`